# JDBC SQL Exception vs Hibernate Exception(JDBC Exception)

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, exception

i am currently learning to code in hibernate and going through some blogs.I came across the following line which says -
**`"JDBC API throws SQLException that is a checked exception, so we need to write a lot of try-catch block code. Most of the times it’s redundant in every JDBC call and used for transaction management. Hibernate wraps JDBC exceptions and throw JDBCException or HibernateException un-checked exception, so we don’t need to write code to handle it. "`**

I know that SQL Exception is a compile time exception and need to be handled.But i am not getting the concept of wrapping a checked exception and throwing it as a non-checked exception.If we can convert a checked to non-checked exception, then why cant we do the same for every checked exception in Java.I understand that i am missing some logic here but please help me out in this.Also,
Can someone explain the real advantage of this?

Answer (score 0):

This is done so developer don't have to wrap every one of your operations regarding Hibernate in try catch blocks.

Here are some details why this it's a useful feature(details [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=bTwfHzMxtQcC&pg=PA439&lpg=PA439&dq=Exceptions%20and%20how%20they%20should%20be%20handled%20always%20end%20in%20heated%20debates%20between%20Java%20developers&source=bl&ots=DtfXThQING&sig=NLuHh-GdFeKcx-Gmb6JHKYY-d4w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-6pWosIPfAhVKtI8KHajOCH4Q6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=Exceptions%20and%20how%20they%20should%20be%20handled%20always%20end%20in%20heated%20debates%20between%20Java%20developers&f=false)):

> Exceptions and how they should be handled always end in heated debates
>   between Java developers. It isn’t surprising that Hibernate has some
>   noteworthy history as well. Until Hibernate 3.x, all exceptions thrown
>   by Hibernate were checked exceptions, so every Hibernate API forced
>   the developer to catch and handle exceptions. This strategy was
>   influenced by JDBC , which also throws only checked exceptions.
>   However, it soon became clear that this doesn’t make sense, because
>   all exceptions thrown by Hibernate are fatal. In many cases, the best
>   a developer can do in this situation is to clean up, display an error
>   message, and exit the application. Therefore, starting with Hibernate
>   3.x, all exceptions thrown by Hibernate are subtypes of the unchecked Runtime Exception, which is usually handled in a single location in an
>   application. This also makes any Hibernate template or wrapper API
>   obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

> why cant we do the same for every checked exception in Java

We absolutely can do it every time, whenever it is useful. Just like in the case, which you describe.

> Can someone explain the real advantage of this?

You need to realize, how useful the `SQLException` really is for your business logic. The answer is: not really. You almost never make decisions in your code based on `SQLException`. If you catch a `SQLException`, you cannot use its information (e.g. message, code) to somehow branch your business logic. The only exception, that I know of, is the `DuplicateKeyException`, which can be used to determine, that a value (e.g. login name, or email) already exist and thus you can skip one select to improve performance.

So, your DAO cannot make use of it, your service too, so you need to propagate it to your controller, catch it, rollback transaction and render an error message to the user. In fact, frameworks do this for you. They allow you to declaratively start a transaction (`@Transactional`), rollback automatically, if an exception escapes from your controller and render an error message using some `ExceptionHandler`.

So you see, that you really want to propagate these exceptions out from your business logic (DAO, service, controller) to the framework. If these exceptions were checked, than you'd need to declare `throws` in all methods in the chain.

That's where the wrapping to unchecked exceptions becomes good practice. They reduce the boilerplate of `throws` in the code.